# Jython standalone jar not able to find site_packages

Tags: java, python, jython, jython-2.7

I'm integrating with Jython to run a python script (which runs fine on its own). I added Jython Standalone 2.7.1 to my pom.xml, however it doesn't seem to recognize packages installed under `site_packages`. I have tried suggestions mentioned like [here](http://bugs.jython.org/issue2143) and [here](http://bugs.jython.org/issue2355). However none of them seem to work. If I move from standalone to non standalone jar I get `ImportError: No module named os`. With standalone jar I am able to move one step further but I get error like below. `test_framework` is one of the packages installed in `site_packages`

```
ImportError: No module named test_framework
```

Here is the code. It seems that some path is not set, but I'm not able to figure out which one.

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("python.home", "x/.m2/repo/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.1");
        props.put("jython.home", "x/.m2/repo/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.1");
        props.put("python.console.encoding", "UTF-8");
        props.put("python.security.respectJavaAccessibility", "false"); 
        props.put("python.import.site", "false");
        Properties preprops = System.getProperties();

        PythonInterpreter.initialize(preprops, props, new String[0]);
        PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();

        interpreter.exec("import sys\n" +
                "sys.path.append('src/test/resources/pythonScript')" +
                "\nimport pythonScript.test_command as sc");
        PyObject someObj = interpreter.eval("sc.TestCommand()");
        PyObject someFunc = someObj.__getattr__("deliver_command");
```

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that some path is not set, but I'm not able to figure out
>   which one.

When you use Jython standalone jar, `python.home` should point to your Lib folder. Extract the Jython standalone jar, copy the 'Lib' folder to some location and point the `python.home` to that path.

```
props.put("python.home", "/path/to/folder/Lib");
```

In order to install packages, copy it to the root of the Lib folder. Example in order to use package 'test_framework' paste it into Lib folder and use `import test_framework` to import the package.

Also when you are using standalone jar, you don't need to set `jython.home` property

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  I fixed it by adding the following to my script:

```
from os.path import split, join
import site

for prefix in set(site.PREFIXES):
    path, subdir = split(prefix)
    if subdir == 'bin':
        lib = join(path, 'lib', 'python2.7', 'site-packages')
        site.addsitedir(lib)
```

My site.PREFIXES has just two duplicate entries, so I use set() to dedup the lit.  An idea I'm not using is to make sure that the path exists before adding it as a site directory.  Also, I've hard-coded the version of Python; someday Jython will graduate to 3.x, and that will need to be re-visited.